# Why do these sample relations have many valid joins but only one composition?

Tags: join, relational-database, relational-algebra, natural-join

I am trying to understand some of the claims from a paper that introduced relational databases. Reference: [https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ezives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf)

The author claims that some example relations have multiple joins but only one composition (see page 385 in the article).

Why is this the case? I wonder because a subset of R * S is a valid join, but not the case for R . S. I don't understand because one can take a valid subset of R . S in the same way as R * S.

R

```
1 a  
1 b
1 c
2 c
2 d
2 e
```

S

```
a  g
b  f
c  f
c  g
d  g
e  f
```

R * S (The natural join, as the author calls it; a subset of this would be a valid join as well.)

```
1 a g  
1 b f
1 c f
1 c g
2 c f
2 c g
2 d g
2 e g
```

R ⋅ S (The natural composition, but the author claims there is only one composition despite the existence of multiple valid joins.)

```
1 f
1 g
2 f
2 g
```

Comment: Remember that this is not a general help forum, but a Q&A site for specific programming problems, and there does not appear to be a programming problem in your question?

Comment: Adrian, see also: cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ask exactly 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question.Put all (but only) what is needed to ask your question in your post, not just at a link. That includes appropriate reference to the paper title & date & publisher. Also quote with credit & formatting what is needed for asking. That includes definitions. PS That paper is sloppy, unclear & has mistakes & uses some terminology differently than now. It is very old & is not good for learning. PS Your argument is not clear. Eg it has 2 "because"s over several sentences. Give a chain of small clear obviously correct steps of reasoning.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. Please delete all but one post. [ask] [meta] [meta.se] **If you phrase to be on-topic where posting** you are likely better off posting at [cs.se]. But: https://stackexchange.com/sites PS You really need to give & use the relevant definitions from the paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If *T* is a composition of *R* with *S*, then by definition, there exists some join *U* of *R* with *S* such that *T* = *π*₁₃(*U*). (Note: since you're asking about a specific paper, I'm using the terms and definitions from that paper; but please be aware that the paper is more than fifty years old, and its terms and definitions do *not* match how they're used today.)

So, let's consider that join *U*.

By definition, *π*₁₂(*U*) = *R* and *π*₂₃(*U*) = *S*.

Therefore, since *R* contains the pair (1, a) and no other pairs of the form (_, a), *U* must contain at least one triple of the form (1, a, _) and no other triples of the form (_, a, _). Likewise, since *S* contains the pair (a, g) and no other pairs of the form (a, _), *U* must contain at least one triple of the form (_, a, g) and no other triples of the form (_, a, _). So *U* must contain the triple (1, a, g), and *T* = *π*₁₃(*U*) must contain the pair (1, g).

And, likewise for every other pair in the natural composition *R*·*S*: for each such pair *p*, there's no way to construct a join *U* such that *π*₁₂(*U*) = *R* and *π*₂₃(*U*) = *S* but *p* ∉ *π*₁₃(*U*).

So *T* = *R*·*S*.

Comment: "By definition, π₁₂(U) = R and π₂₃(U) = S." That happens to be true with the example in the paper (Fig. 10 output from Fig 5. inputs). But in general, joins/compositions are 'lossy'. (For example, there could be a {supplier, part} in R for which the part doesn't appear in S.) You'd get the impression from this paper that Codd expects all joins/compositions to be 'lossless', but although Codd 1970 is a seminal paper, it's early days in the evolution of the Relational Model. He just plain got some stuff wrong.

Comment: @AntC: Thanks for your comment! I see what you're saying, but I don't quite agree. It's not like Codd fails to consider lossy examples like yours; rather, he explicitly defines two relations to be "joinable" only if they're "joinable without loss of information", and he defines the term "join" accordingly. Since that time, we've found it useful to define "join" more broadly, so we no longer use Codd's definition; but it's not like his definition was *wrong*. I've now edited this answer to add a note clarifying this.